# Wildcard in main-dex-list during dex file creation

Tags: android, dex, dx

I would like to have all of my classes in specified package reside in main dex file.

Is there option to use a wildcard there?

Comment: Starting with 2.2.0 gradle plugin you can explicitly tell what package to keep in main dex file with proguard syntax `multiDexKeepProguard` http://stackoverflow.com/a/39821351/624706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, wildcards are not supported.
However, you can generate the main-dex-list file using [this script](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/dx/etc/mainDexClasses).
See [my blogpost](http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/generating-main-dex-list-file.html) for more details.