# How to put specific classes into main DEX file?

Tags: android, gradle, dex, amazon-marketplace

We found an issue on Amazon market that IAP doesn't work if it's receivers located not in main `DEX` file.
The question is how to force `gradle` to put specific classes (receivers) into main `DEX` file.

Here are the gradle DEX settings:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
    dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=class_files.txt" 
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
compile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0')
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With Android Plugin for Gradle, Revision 2.2.0 (Released in September 2016) you can use [multiDexKeepFile](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/2.2/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:multiDexKeepFile) api

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
            multiDexEnabled true
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex_keep_file.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

Where `multidex_keep_file.txt` is file with single class per line which needs to be explicitly added to the main dex

```
 com/example/MyClass.class
 com/example/MyClass2.class
```

You can also use `multiDexKeepProguard` to keep whole package

```
-keep class com.example.** { *; }
```

Comment: Hi, this solution is not working for me, can you check my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600992/multidexkeepfile-ignored-not-working

Comment: The `multiDexKeepProguard` part is what worked for me.

Comment: What can I do, if I want use multiDexKeepProguard, and exclude some classes from maindex?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The main point was that you have to set "minSdkVersion 16" before "multiDexEnabled true" else your Application class could be placed in the second dex and app will crash on android lower 5.0

Comment: could you link to official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

No need to manually add multi-dex parameters to dex tasks.
This can be automatically handled by the android plugin (since v0.14.0).

Remove both the *afterEvaluate* section and *compile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0')* from your build.gradle, and instead add this:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled = true
   }
}
```

The plugin is smart enough to package all the components (receivers among them) in main dex file.

Answer (score 0):

Sergii Pechenizkyi's answar only keep some class in main dex , but not generate two dex. Add `--minimal-main-dex` to your `builg.gradle`. But this only solve below `gradle1.5.0`. You can use [DexKnifePlugin](https://github.com/ceabie/DexKnifePlugin) to solve your problem.

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
    dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=class_files.txt" 
    dx.additionalParameters += '--minimal-main-dex'
    }
}
```